# Reorder objects in a Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I am trying to reorder following array. Actually sorting is
based on the `sourcelocation.orderindex`, every object has its corresponding
another object (with `rider_id` same) along with `is_dropoff` field `true`, I want to reorder the array in the following way.

Step 1: Objects for which `sourceindex` is `0` should be on top, in our
case top 3 object will be on top now next object must have `sourcelocation.order` greater then `0` and `is_dropoff` true please note `destinationlocation.orderindex` must not be greater then forthcoming objects `sourcelocation.orderindex` value.

```
let inputSet = [
  {
    "sourcelocation": {
      "orderindex": "0"
    },
    "destinationlocation": {
      "orderindex": "1"
    },
    "rider_ids": "2b7116ea3dead9870b828a1v"
  },
  {
    "sourcelocation": {
      "orderindex": "0"
    },
    "destinationlocation": {
      "orderindex": "1"
    },
    "rider_ids": "4b7116ea3dead9870b828a19"
  },
  {
    "sourcelocation": {
      "orderindex": "0"
    },
    "destinationlocation": {
      "orderindex": "3"
    },
    "rider_ids": "548e653d56060c83838b772e"
  },
  {
    "rider_ids": "2b7116ea3dead9870b828a1v",
    "is_dropoff": true,
    "address": {
      "orderindex": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "rider_ids": "4b7116ea3dead9870b828a19",
    "is_dropoff": true,
    "address": {
      "orderindex": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "rider_ids": "548e653d56060c83838b772e",
    "is_dropoff": true,
    "address": {
      "orderindex": "3"
    }
  },
  {
    "sourcelocation": {
      "orderindex": "2"
    },
    "destinationlocation": {
      "orderindex": "3"
    },
    "rider_ids": "5b8e676d56060c83838b772e"
  },
  {
    "rider_ids": "5b8e676d56060c83838b772e",
    "is_dropoff": true,
    "address": {
      "orderindex": "3"
    }
  }
]
```

The following must be the response that I am expecting

```
let outputSet = [
  {
    "sourcelocation": {
      "orderindex": "0"
    },
    "destinationlocation": {
      "orderindex": "1"
    },
    "rider_ids": "2b7116ea3dead9870b828a1v"
  },
  {
    "sourcelocation": {
      "orderindex": "0"
    },
    "destinationlocation": {
      "orderindex": "1"
    },
    "rider_ids": "4b7116ea3dead9870b828a19"
  },
  {
    "sourcelocation": {
      "orderindex": "0"
    },
    "destinationlocation": {
      "orderindex": "3"
    },
    "rider_ids": "548e653d56060c83838b772e"
  },
  {
    "rider_ids": "2b7116ea3dead9870b828a1v",
    "is_dropoff": true,
    "address": {
      "orderindex": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "rider_ids": "4b7116ea3dead9870b828a19",
    "is_dropoff": true,
    "address": {
      "orderindex": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "sourcelocation": {
      "orderindex": "2"
    },
    "destinationlocation": {
      "orderindex": "3"
    },
    "rider_ids": "5b8e676d56060c83838b772e"
  },
  {
    "rider_ids": "5b8e676d56060c83838b772e",
    "is_dropoff": true,
    "address": {
      "orderindex": "3"
    }
  },
  {
    "rider_ids": "548e653d56060c83838b772e",
    "is_dropoff": true,
    "address": {
      "orderindex": "3"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: you haven't `sourceindex` properties in your objects

Comment: @ArtyomAmiryan Its sourcelocation.orderindex , I updated, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Can anyone please help. Thanks.

Comment: More people will help if you make an attempt first rather than just asking for the solution, start with something like [inputSet.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over your data, copying each item to a new array

Comment: @Lloyd I experimented with it and trying to get solution since last 2 days, Intresting thing is you cant do it with just a loop , you will need to take care of conditions as well which I mentioned earlier. Thanks

Comment: This is not complete solution but this thread may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value

Comment: sorting is a very common, very old problem, and yes you will use a loop, conditions, and probably recursion depending on your method of choice, sorting is something you definitely want to spend some time learning from start to finish.

Comment: @Lloyd I did all of that but doing something fishy which fails for certain cases, When  I felt hopeless then I headed to stackoverflow community, Hope someone can help me in figuring out the solution. Thanks